# How to change the update that the client send to the server Tensorflow Federated

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I'm trying to understand how Tensorflow Federated Works, using the simple_fedavg as example.

I still don't understand how to change what the client send to the server, for example.

I don't want to send all the weights of the update, i want to send a list formed like this:

```
  test[index] = test_stc.stc_compression(test[index], sparsification_rate)
```

Where `test_stc.stc_compression(test[index], sparsification_rate)` return 5 values: `negatives, positives, average, original_shape, new_shape`, then i would like to access those information on the server side before running the  `round_model_delta = tff.federated_mean(client_outputs.weights_delta, weight=weight_denom)` for creating the weights that i will use for the `tff.federated_mean`.

So, basically, i would like to change `client_update` to send a list that i have created instead of all the weights and then, on the server create a custom list of weights using the information that the client sent. Only after the creation of the new custom list of weight i would like the server to update the model.

I actually tried to change the `return ClientOutput(test, client_weight, loss_sum / client_weight)` of the `client_update`, but then i don't know how to access the `test` variable on the server and in which procedure/function i would need to do it.

I hope that i made myself clear enough since my main language is not english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`tff.federated_aggregate`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/federated_aggregate) operator which exposes the control you probably need (I am not sure I follow what that is), including what computation should be done on each client value at server before being added to an aggregation accumulator.

You can think of the mentioned `tff.federated_mean` as a special case of this general operator.